# Cannot install sprockets gem - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, rubygems

I accidently uninstalled the sprockets gem in terminal using this command

> 'gem uninstall sprockets 2.12.3'

when I try to install it again with this command:

> 'gem install sprockets 2.12.3'

I get this message:

> 'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>       Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) for "au-m.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sprockets-2.12.3.gemspec.rz)'

I was wondering if anyone knows what I need to do to rectify this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`au-m.rubygems.org` might be temporarily down.

try it.

```
$ gem source --remove https://rubygems.org/
$ gem source --add https://tokyo-m.rubygems.org/
```

Comment: This should be used only as a temporary workaround, until the rubygems.org infrastructure issues are resolved by them. This should not be used as a general solution as it puts unnecessary strain in the tokyo node and gets packages from a node probably far away from the user.